# Storing 3D points into a database

Tags: database, 3d, blob, points

I am actualy working on a database in which I have to store meteorological 3D points. With my partner we have diffrent point of view in the way of storing it. He would prefer to create a table of Points with one point for each line, and for me it was more appropriate to store the points for a given date/peripheral in a BLOB.

What do you think ?

Thanks

PS : we are also arguing about the DB we should use (SQLite, MySQL,...) if you have ideas, you are welcome !

Comment: This all depends on what you're using the points for, do multiple entities have points or just meteorological records? Are you ever going to load the points without the meteorological data?

Comment: we will always relate the points to their value, each time, we do not need to load the points without their value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All depends on whether you need to to write queries to get particular points. ie find me all the thingies with Points with an X < 300. If you don't have much relational stuff to do, and you are going down the blob route then you should consider one of the NoSql variants.

It's decision you should make based on your functional needs not a purist approach to relational db design.

Comment: Actually we should not have to get particular points. Normally we ask for a particular record and load all the values for this record. here comes the question : should we store a the values in a blob atached to the record or have a table of values in which we pickup the values corresponding to the requested record

Comment: Thought I'd made that clear, if you don't need to select based on individual points, then blob is the way to go in my opinion. That said  NoSql will deal with this sort of data much better than a RDBMS. If you normalise, theres a significant cost in data size, indexing etc, if you don't need to get indiviudual points it's a cost that's hard to justify.